# How to use product form with custom and configuration option on my custom .phtml file?

Tags: magento2

I want to 2 products in a loop using SKU. But after integration below code products are visible and add to the cart it also working fine, but the product's custom options and configuration options are not visible. Can anyone please guide what I missing?

I put the bellow code in the form.phtml file theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/view/

```
<?php 
$_complete_set_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('complete_set_sku')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
//print_r($_complete_set_attributeValue);
if ($_complete_set_attributeValue)
{
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/popup_comeplete_set_product.phtml")->toHtml();
}
?>
```

I have created popup_comeplete_set_product.phtml in theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$helperImport = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$cartHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$_helper =    $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');  
$postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
$productTypeInstance = $objectManager->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable');
$typeInstance = $objectManager->get('Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped');
//$typeInstance = $objectManager->get('Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type');

$collection   = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')                
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('BAB','PRI'));                
$total_product_count = $collection->count();

<div class="popup-complete-set-block product-add-form <?= $block->escapeHtml($product->getSku()) ?>">
                        <form style="width: 100%;display: flex;" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($product->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getId() ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                            <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_top') ?>
                            
                            <?php if (!$block->hasOptions()):?>
                                <?= $block->getChildHtml('product_info_form_content') ?>
                            <?php else:?>
                                <?php if ($product->isSaleable() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container1'):?>
                                    <?= $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                    
                            <?php if ($product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container2'):?>
                                <?= $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                            <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_bottom') ?>                          
                        
                            <div class="popup-complete-set-image">
                                <img src="<?php echo  $resizedImageUrl; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName() ?>" />
                            </div>                              
                            <div class="popup-complete-set-detail">
                                <p class="slide-number"><?php echo $counter++;?> / <?php echo $total_product_count;?></p>
                                <h3 class="slide-title"><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $product->getName() ?></a></h3>
                                <p class="slide-price">
                                    <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($product);?>                                     
                                </p>                                    
                                <?php if ($product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <div class="box-tocart">
                                        <div class="fieldset">
                                            <?php //if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
                                            <div class="field qty">
                                                <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                                                <div class="control">
                                                    
                                                    <div class="sp-quantity">
                                                        <div class="sp-minus fff"> <a class="ddd" href="#">-</a></div>
                                                        <div class="sp-input">
                                                            <input type="number"
                                                               name="qty"
                                                               id="qty"
                                                               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                                                               title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                                                               class="input-text qty quntity-input"
                                                               style="border: 0px solid #dfdfdf !important;border-radius: 0 !important;height: 43px;"
                                                               data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                                                               />
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="sp-plus fff"> <a class="ddd" href="#">+</a></div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php //endif; ?>
                                            <div class="actions">
                                                <button type="submit"
                                                        title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                                                        class="action primary tocart product-form-cart"
                                                        id="product-addtocart-button">
                                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
                                                    <svg fill="#fff" height="20" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1171 960q0 13-10 23l-466 466q-10 10-23 10t-23-10l-50-50q-10-10-10-23t10-23l393-393-393-393q-10-10-10-23t10-23l50-50q10-10 23-10t23 10l466 466q10 10 10 23z"></path></svg>
                                                </button>
                                                <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                    <?php if ($product->getIsSalable()) : ?>
                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the method get AddToCartUrl in `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php`

```
protected $_cartHelper;

   public function __construct(
        .....
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper,,
        .....

    ) {
        $this->_cartHelper = $_cartHelper;
    }
    public function getAddToCartUrl($product)
    {   
        $additional=array();
        return $this->_cartHelper->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
    }
```